# Gradle Error:Gradle DSL method not found: 'executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure()'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-sdk-tools

I've recently updated android SDK tools to v23 and now when I open a project of mine it cannot compile, im getting this message:

`Error:Gradle DSL method not found: 'executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure()'`

Does someone knows what can be the issue here?
Here is my app.gradle code:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
apply plugin: 'com.raizlabs.griddle'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.3.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile('com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.5.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }
    //http
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    //db
    apt 'com.raizlabs.android:DBFlow-Compiler:2.2.1'
    compile 'com.raizlabs.android:DBFlow-Core:2.2.1'
    compile 'com.raizlabs.android:DBFlow:2.2.1'
    //graph
    compile 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.1.3'

    compile project(':mobihelp_sdk_android_v1.5.1')
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'

    compile 'com.apptentive:apptentive-android:1.7.3@aar'

    compile "com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:4.6.2"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1+"
    compile 'com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.1.0@aar'

    compile 'com.readystatesoftware.systembartint:systembartint:1.0.3'
}
```

Comment: I got the same error after attempting to enable instant run on a project by updating its dependencies to the latest version of gradle (2.8) and to the 2.0-alpha3 android wrapper..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed mine by closing Adroid Studio and then

```
$ cd <project root>
$ rm -r .idea
```

Then start up Android Studio and re-open your project. This forces Gradle to build the project again and hopefully your issue will be sorted.

Answer (score 6):

I might be late to the party, but my case is different, i need to import 2 maven URL, so what i did write in gradle is :

```
maven 
{
    url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public', 
    url 'https://jitpack.io
}
```

where i should've write like this :

```
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
```

Answer (score 2):

Go to <kbd>File</kbd> > <kbd>Settings</kbd> > <kbd>Build, Execution, Deployment</kbd> > <kbd>Build Tools</kbd> > <kbd>Gradle</kbd>

Make sure you select <kbd>Use default gradle wrapper (recommended)</kbd> at Project-level settings.

[Project-level settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmiwl.png)

Answer (score -1):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
```

> This should be in your **project level gradle file**
>
> And other dependencies in your **app level gradle file**

Comment: Tried this and it doesnt solve my issue. You are maybe right - im not that of a gradle expert but this was working before. Do you think something else can be the issue here?

Comment: could you try removing classpath and try building again?